# HTTPS to HTTP - Response appears cached, or maybe this doesn't work.

Tags: apache-2.2, https, cache

Long story short:

Google cached `https://` links, when this website doesn't need an SSL - 
The SSL is expired now, and people are getting that warning screen when coming from Google.

Thus, we found this apache configuration:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And it works -
For me, exclusively, apparently.

So, my question is -- why does it work for me, but not some other people --

And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users will still get a warning screen if they go to a https site that redirects - the redirect happens **after** the warning, not prior. Chances are you've just accepted the warning already.

Google will eventually re-index and use the http versions, but until then your best option is to pay the $7 bucks or so for a valid SSL.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said - and I demonstrated with a PHP-driven 301, but I popped in the Apache code, and it works on mine - even in a new browser + incognito mode ---- albeit, on second glance, it isn't actually working in FF --

Comment: Oh, nope, you're right. I had an incognito window still open that had cached my acceptance of the invalid SSL.